# angularjs: route redirection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have been using ui-router $stateProvider state manager for my application but I haven't defined any routes using $routeProvider.

Now, I would like my urls to be rewritten this way:

```
http://mydomain/app/feature
```

to

```
http://mydomain/feature
```

the /app folder being the folder that contains my angularjs application as well as the index.html page.

How should I do that ?

Comment: I think this is a server side configuration.

Comment: [See this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location), particularly the sections on html5mode and link rewriting

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a server side configuration as @DeividiCavarzan said. I made something like that on apache2, setting Aliases on myApp.conf file whereI was able to do things like:

```
Alias /myMainPage /app/views/main.html
```

Hope I've been helpfull.